# Get multiple values from 1 select tag in a form to display in different fields in a table

Tags: html, html-select

This is my code for the 'select' tag:

```
<select name="val[Payee_Name]" required>
    <option value="101| A">A</option>
    <option value="102| B">B</option>
    <option value="103| C">C</option>
</select>
```

I want the values (101,102,103) to be displayed in a different field in the table (`Payee_Code` field, not `Payee_Name` field).  How can I do that?

Comment: ever thought about javascript ?

Comment: make the question more clear on what you want? What table are you talking about?

Comment: sorry if my question is not really clear. Let's say my table name is Payee.In this table i have some fields which are Payee_Name, Payee_Code etc. I want the Payee_Code to be automatically been grabbed by database when i choose the Payee_Name in a form, so firstly i need to assign the Payee_Code for each Payee_Name(A,B,C) right?then how can i grab the Payee_Code value(101,102,103) that have been assigned in the above form to be in Payee_Code field? hope u get what i mean

Answer (score 0):

After submitting your form you can easily get the payee_code in form data. You also don't need to use the `payee_code | payee_name` in the option value. You can just take `payee_code` in that and after click on submit button. You can access the payee_code which the user selected.

Let's consider if you are using PHP, then you may do so by:

```
<form method="post" action="check_payer.php">
   <select name="Payee_Name" required>
       <option value="101">A</option>
       <option value="102">B</option>
       <option value="103">C</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

In your `check_payer.php`

```
<?php 
   if($_POST)
   {
      if($_POST['Payee_Name'] == '101')
      {
         echo 'A'; // You can also make it dynamic if you are using any database.
      }
      else if($_POST['Payee_Name'] == '102')
      {
         echo 'B';
      }
   }    
?>
```

Kindly ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: That is also not a problem. You can use the Payee_name (A,B,C) in the value part of options. And check it check_payer.php

Comment: ok thanx for your help.but then, how can i grab the value (101,102,103) to be in Payee_Code field? because later i have to display the records where Payee_Name and Payee_Code are separated.

Comment: You can check it in if condition like `if($_POST['Payee_Name'] == 'A') {echo 'Payee_code = 101';}`. Kindly ask if still not worked for you.

Comment: No matter what you are using. Your flow of accessing the value should be valid. This may only be the reason.